# Herbrand Base and definite programs

Tags: logic, first-order-logic

I know the definition of Herbrand Universe and Herbrand Base. But i haven't clearly understood why applying the herbrand base to a definite program leads to a model.
The fact is that an herbrand base doesn't carry information about the predicate symbols that populate the base, so how can i know if the elements of herbrand base are true or false ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $S$ be a formula in clausal where $P_1, \ldots, P_k$ are the
*predicate* symbols, $f_1,\ldots, f_l$ the *function* symbols and $a_1, \ldots, a_m$ the *constant* symbols occurring in $S$.

Let $H_S$ be the *Herbrand universe* for $S$, i.e. the set of ground terms that can be formed from constants and function symbols in $S$.

Let $B_S$, the *Herbrand base* for $S$, the set of *ground* atomic formulas that can be formed from predicate symbols in $S$ and terms in $H_S$.

Consider a simple example:

> $S = \{ \{ ¬P(a,f (x, y)) \}, \{ P(b,f (x, y)) \} \}$.

We have that:

> $H_S = \{ a, b, f (a, a), f (a, b), f (b, a), f (b, b), f (a,f (a, a)),\ldots \}$

and:

> $B_S = \{ P(a,f (a, a)), P(a,f (a, b)), P(a,f (b, a)), P(a,f (b, b)), \ldots,
> P(a, f (a, f (a, a))), \ldots, P(b, f (a, a)), P(b, f (a, b)), P(b, f (b, a)), P(b, f (b, b)), \ldots, P(b, f (a, f (a, a))), \ldots \}$.

To get an *Herbrand interpretation* for $S$ we have to carve out from $B_S$ the subset corresponding to a relation $R_P$ that interpret the predicate symbol $P$, for example:

> $R_P = \{ P(b,f (a, a)), P(b,f (a, b)), P(b,f (b, a)), P(b,f (b, b)) \}$.

---

Maybe useful to note two facts:

- in the case that $S$ has no constants, we add some constant, say $a$, to form ground terms;
- if *function* symbols are present, the Herbrand universe will be infinite.